# Configuring terminal type for Remote-SSH on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm using Remote-SSH for VSCode to connect to a linux server for development. I need my terminal type to default to xterm instead of xterm-256color which seems to be the default terminal type when using Remote-SSH.

I have tried adding `SetEnv TERM=xterm` as well as `SendEnv TERM=xterm` to the SSH config file but neither works. The only way I can get it to work is by manually running `export TERM=xterm` in the bash terminal once I'm connected, but this setting is lost when I open a new bash.

In VSCode, I can see that my [terminal for linux is set to xterm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdXcu.png) so I'm not sure why it's still defaulting to xterm-256color when using Remote-SSH. I don't have this problem when using Putty outside of VSCode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you are referring to in your screenshot does not set the `TERM` variable but the executable that is run if you're using an external terminal.

Seems like the `TERM` value for the integrated terminal [is hardcoded to `xterm-256color`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/7fca8ee82da20a0130af6dbe9999f5c073b2d8c7).

Easy workaround should be to set it in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` on the remote:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately even after I add `export TERM=xterm` to both ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile, I still get the same problem. Is the hard-coding or something in remote-ssh configuration overwriting this? As mentioned, I don't have this problem when using Putty.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. PUTTY obviously uses `xterm` in your case (can be configured in PUTTY settings), that's probably why it works there. If it also works when setting it manually after login, it should definitely work in your `.profile` as well. Can you check your `.bashrc` file? There's usually an if-statement which checks the `TERM` variable. Ultimate hack would be to set it right before that.

Comment: Cheers, that did it! I didn't have a .bashrc file in my profile for some reason, I created it and added `export TERM=xterm` and it now defaults to that. Thanks for your help!